# oracle search within a radius with latitude and longitude

Tags: sql, oracle, coordinates, oracle-spatial

I have a oracle DB with a table like this:

| name | start_lat | start_lon | end_lat | end_lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10.52 | 8.57 | 12.24 | 9.32 |
| b | 15.65 | 25.67 | 14.77 | 26.32 |
| c | 12.88 | 17.85 | 16.95 | 20.25 |

Now I need to add data in a new column named start_location when the start coordinates are in a defined point (for example lat: 10.10 and lon: 9.25) with a radius of 100KM. Also the same for a new column named end_location

The result should look something like this:

| name | start_lat | start_lon | end_lat | end_lon | start_location | end_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10.52 | 8.57 | 12.24 | 9.32 | location x | location y |
| b | 15.65 | 25.67 | 14.77 | 26.32 | location z | location x |
| c | 12.88 | 17.85 | 16.95 | 20.25 | location y | location z |

How can I do that?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What is *a defined point with a radius of 100 km*? Please show us the results that you want.

Comment: The defined point is a location with coordinates. I have added the result on the post

Comment: You should start by learning about Oracle's support for spatial data:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/introduction-spatial-data.htm#SPATL442.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Do you mean that `start_location` should contain a buffer of 100km around the point defined by `start_lat` and `end_lat` ? I.e. a circle with a radius of 100km ?